# How to write an if statement in access?

Tags: ms-access

I want to state a condition in a new field that if the Date of row 2 is greater than row 1 then Subtract field from row 2 - field from row 1 else leave blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing the [`iif` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) , which you can insert your conditions in with the general form:

```
iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )
```

Comment: how do I state that Date of row 2 is greater than date of row 1 in a general form. There are about 800,000 rows.